# Intersection observer multi usage

Tags: javascript, html, css, intersection-observer

I'm familiar with the intersection observer, however i'm stuck on how to use it with different elements that has different animations consider the following :

```
<div id="hero">
  <h1>hello world<h1>
</div>

<div class="nav">
  <li>nav item</li>
  <li>nav item</li>
  <li>nav item</li>
</div>
```

now let's say when the div with id of hero comes to view port move it to the left

```
const io = new IntersectionObserver((entries, observer) => {
    entries.forEach((entry) => {
      if (entry.isIntersecting) {
        const hero = entry.target
        hero.style.transform = 'translateX(30px)'
        observer.unobserve(target)
      }
    })
  })
  io.observe(document.querySelector('#hero'))
```

now that's totally fine but what if i want to watch another element and give different style

currently i'm just copying the same code and changing the target and what i would like to do like so

```
const io2 = new IntersectionObserver((entries, observer) => {
    entries.forEach((entry) => {
      if (entry.isIntersecting) {
        const hero = entry.target
        hero.style.opacity = 0;
        observer.unobserve(target)
      }
    })
  })
  io.observe(document.querySelector('.nav'))
```

that's of course very repetitive, and if i have another element i would end up just copying the same exact more with few changes

so how to implement a better solution without repeating myself over and over

Comment: You could try to list all the targets and then loop through them with a `for` or `forEach` loop, maybe?

Comment: Hello again, I have posted an answer to the topic you can check it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after I read your question again I understood what you want, and I made this script for you! hope it helps!

```js
const Observe = (target, onIntersection) => {
  // Let's create a new IntersectionObserver instance
  const io = new IntersectionObserver((entries, observer) => {
  
      // Loop through every entry
      entries.forEach((entry) => {
        // Check if the entry is intersecting
        // And validate the callback function
        if( !entry.isIntersecting || !onIntersection || typeof onIntersection !== "function" ) return;
        
        // Fire the callback function
        onIntersection(entry);
        
        // Tell the observer to stop observing
        observer.unobserve(target);
     });
  });
  
  // Start a observing the target
  io.observe(target);
}
```

```html
<div id="hero">
  <h1>hello world<h1>
</div>

<div class="nav">
  <li>nav item</li>
  <li>nav item</li>
  <li>nav item</li>
</div>


<script>

  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ()=>{
    
     Observe( document.querySelector("#hero"), function(entry){
     
        const hero = entry.target;
        hero.style.transform = 'translateX(30px)';
        
     
     } );
     
     Observe( document.querySelector(".nav"), function(entry){
     
        const hero = entry.target
        hero.style.opacity = 0;
        
     
     } );
    
  });

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i appreciate that a lot